# how to get source code line from instruction address in gdb

Tags: gcc, gdb, disassembly

I'm trying to get disassembly of instruction at address A, so I write

```
(gdb) x/i 0x00007f8aba6ad96c
   0x7f8aba6ad96c <laprintf+167>:   nop
```

But how do I get which line in source code it corresponds to? debugging symbols are available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it: you can use

```
list *addr
```

command in GDB to get source-code information about that address.

Comment: Surprised that there have been not many ups. Thanks for finding it!