# Get source location for address at runtime using debug information

Tags: c, debugging, memory-address, addr2line

In my C program, I have an instruction pointer that points to some address in virtual memory, e.g., a function pointer.
I would like to map this address to the corresponding source location (file path, line number) using the debug information in the executed binary at runtime.
I know that [GDB implements something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162112/how-to-get-source-code-line-from-instruction-address-in-gdb), but am unsure how to approach this for my project.

I'm aware of [addr2line](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/addr2line.1.html) and [llvm-symbolizer](https://www.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-symbolizer.html), but both of those tools analyze addresses in ELF files, not binaries that are already loaded into virtual memory.
Similarly, this is not a duplicate of [How do I access the `addr2line` functionality within my C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556321/how-do-i-access-the-addr2line-functionality-within-my-c-program)

Comment: "those tools analyze addresses in ELF files" -- that's exactly what GDB is doing though; you need to determine the binary that was loaded at the given address, and then go to the debug information in that ELF to determine the source location. The first part can be done with `dladdr` as described in the 2nd question you linked; the 2nd part can be done with `addr2line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Yakov Galka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277176/yakov-galka)'s comment, I found a solution for what I want to do:

```
#define __USE_GNU
#include <dlfcn.h>

// instruction address for which I want the source location
const void* code_addr = 0xabcdef;

// call dladdr to figure out base address in virtual memory
Dl_info info;
dladdr(code_addr, &info);

size_t base_address = (size_t) info.dli_fbase;
size_t relative_address = ((size_t) code_addr) - base_address;
// in my case: relative_address == 0x126c
```

Then, I can call `addr2line` to determine the source location. In my case, everything is liked into `a.out`, so I can just call

```
addr2line --basenames -i -e tasks.out 0x126c
```

which then prints something like:

```
filename.c:42
```